# I need to draw a Circle with text in the middle, help please

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, geometry, gridbaglayout

Hi I need to make a circle that can have text in the middle. 
At the moment I can draw circles but I don't know how to adapt them in order to place text in the middle.

If anyone can show me how to do this or help me in anyway I would be grateful.

Thanks,
Shihab

Comment: I think we need more information. Are you using a `Graphics` object?

Comment: if you use Canvas, then you can do it using graphics.drawString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drawing a circle in Swing:

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //Adding  super.paintComponent....  
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawOval(0, 0, g.getClipBounds().width, g.getClipBounds().height);
    }
}
```

For adding text inside the circle you can use **GridBagLayout**.i.e.

```
CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints cl;
cl = new GridBagConstraints();
cl.gridy = 0;
panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"), cl);
```

Here is the Link in that you can use swing to draw a circle using Canvas.

[Draw canvas with color and text](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawcanvaswithcolorandtext.htm)

Comment: Don't forget to call super.paintComponent otherwise you'll end up with everything that was previously painted to the Graphics context appearing on your component

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Yes. Added and Modified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). Then you can create a `ShapeIcon` and add the Icon to a JLabel. Then you can use the JLabel to display the text centered on the Icon:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ShapeIcon(...) );
label.setText( "Centered Text" );
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

You will need to make sure the shape is large enough to contain the text.